# How to Index nested json objects in solr

Tags: json, solr, indexing

I have a json object like this,

```
{  
"id" : "123",  
"name" : "aaa",  
"loc" : {  
 "lat" : "",  
 "lon" : ""  
},  
}
```

In solr i added a field like

```
<field name="loc" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then i tried adding the json doc to solr
But i couldn't see the 'loc' object being indexed in solr.
Am i doing wrong? Do i need to add anything in schema.xml
Can someone help me out of this pls?

Answer (score 1):

I afraid you have to flatten the nested object to become something like

```
loc_lat = value of loc.lat
loc_lon = value of loc.lon
```

And of course, two new fields to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

How are you adding your JSON? Because it does not look like [the format required by Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON).

You need to conform to that. Also, if those lat/longs are really geographic coordinates, Solr has a dedicated [geospatial support](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch). Though you will need to get data into the appropriate shape either on the client side or with something like [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor), most likely [ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html).

Answer (score 0):

post to

/solr/update/json?commit=true?**split=/&f=txt:/****

see http://lucidworks.com/blog/schemaless-solr-part-1/